# fatal error: itkMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter.h: No such file or directory #include "itkMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter.h"

Tags: image-segmentation, itk

I am trying to run the itkMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter program for blood vessels segmentation given in the below link

https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Nonunit/Review/SegmentBloodVesselsWithMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasure/Documentation.html

But I am getting the following error.

fatal error: itkMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter.h: No such file or directory

I am unable to understand that for Input, 2D slice/image should give or 3D image series of CT scan?

Also, I tried the code from 
https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageFeature/SegmentBloodVessels/Documentation.html

but this is also not working.

Can Someone please provide the solution?

Answer (score 0):

With ITK 4.x and earlier, some of the classes were in `Review` module, which is turned off by default. That means you need to set CMake variable `Module_ITKReview` to **ON** when configuring/compiling ITK.